# Make User Profile Visible to All Users Include AnonyMouseUser() on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create UserProfileView with user's username in the url. Actually, it works somehow with the actual settings. The issue is, any username extension in the url redirects to the logged in user's profile. And, no info comes to the template when I try to go to profile without signing in. Here's my code, any help is appreciated.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
  bio = models.TextField(max_length=280, blank=True)
  avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='avatars/')

  def __str__(self):
    return '@{}'.format(self.user.username)

  def save(self):
    super().save()

    img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
      output_size = (300, 300)
      img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.BICUBIC)
      img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileView(SelectRelatedMixin, TemplateView):
  model = Profile
  template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
  select_related = ('user',)

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('accounts:profile', kwargs={'user': self.object.user})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('<str:username>/', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
]
```

profile.html (how I call the related data in the template)

```
<h3>{{ user.profile }}</h3>
      <p>{{ user.profile.email }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.profile.bio }}</p>
        <h3>{{ profile }}</h3>
```

*update for clearer explanation:

[here's the user profile when tried without login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O94wh.png)

[and same user's profile here when logged in. actually, it should display the profile of user with the username in url. but, it always shows the current user's profile on any url.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LiEO.png)

Comment: Not very clear what's your issue is

Comment: Tried to add example pics of the issue. hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Do you have `username` field on `User` or on `Profile` model? Trying to figure out why you're using a view for a Profile instead of just for User...

Comment: that's right, User model have the username attr. Also, Profile model is connected by OneToOneField with the User model.

Comment: So can you just create `UserView` instead of `UserProfileView` that uses `User` model instead of `Profile`? Wouldn't it be simpler? I see that in the template you access `profile` via `user.profile` anyway...

Comment: Tried but still renders the current user's info to the template on any url. Also, get_queryset function hasn't worked. Which is;
```def get_queryset(self):
  queryset = super().get_queryset()
  return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('user.username'))```

Comment: The code in the comment didn't stand on blocks. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `BaseDetailView`, define `get_object` method and add `'user'` to context:

```py
class UserProfileView(SelectRelatedMixin, BaseDetailView, TemplateView):
  model = Profile
  template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
  select_related = ('user',)

  def get_object(self):
   return self.get_queryset().get(user__username=self.kwargs['username'])

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    content['user'] = self.object.user
    return context
```

Alternatively, you can base your view on `User` model, not `Pofile` (I think it's a bit simpler this way):

```py
class UserProfileView(SelectRelatedMixin, BaseDetailView, TemplateView):
  model = User
  template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
  select_related = ('profile',)

  def get_object(self):
   return self.get_queryset().get(username=self.kwargs['username'])

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    content['user'] = self.object
    return context
```

Or you can even don't bother adding `'user'` to context and just access user in the template via `object`

Comment: Updated my answer with some fixes

Comment: Yeah, it works! `SingleObjectMixin` didn't work without any objects at first but, `BaseDetailView` has done the job for me. Thanks for the effort, appreciated!

Comment: Btw, I think you can also replace `BaseDetailView` + `TemplateVIew` by just using `DetailView`